# Trying to implement a polyline but it doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, mkoverlay

I am trying to get a polyline which should be there in my track application. I have gone through various questions and websites regarding this but I can't really guess where I am going wrong. It will be great if someone can help me out? :)

My Code -->

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

[linerArray addObject:currentLocation];

CLLocationDegrees lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees lngt= currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

CLLocationCoordinate2D lccoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lngt);






NSInteger calculateCoordinates= linerArray.count;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[calculateCoordinates];


for (NSInteger initialStart= 0; initialStart < calculateCoordinates; initialStart ++) {
    CLLocation *lct = [linerArray objectAtIndex:initialStart];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cord2 = lct.coordinate;

    coordinates[initialStart] = cord2;
}

//drawing a polyline
MKPolyline *pline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:calculateCoordinates];
    [self.viewMap addOverlay:pline];

}

//Designing overlay polyline or setting polyine view


-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    MKPolylineRenderer *polylineRender = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    polylineRender.lineWidth = 7.0f;
    polylineRender.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return polylineRender;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the MKMapViewDelegate protocol declared on your view controller?

Comment: What debugging have you done and what were the results?  Is didUpdateLocations getting called? Is rendererForOverlay getting called?  Is the map view's `delegate` property set?  (The protocol declaration is just to make the compiler happy.)  Did you do alloc+init on linerArray?

Comment: Also note the code shown adds a new overlay for the _entire_ route every time the location changes.  You should call removeOverlays before adding the updated route otherwise you will end up with lots of unnecessary duplicate routes on top of each other.